# Converting images to grayscale using Python

Tags: python, rgb

i have to convert a image from, rgb scale to grayscale image using only 4 lines, in "insert code part", I can do this using CV, but instead I have convert a color image to Black and White, by calculate the average of the RGB values. If the average is closer to 255, the pixel is set to white (255), otherwise to black (0). For conversion to a greyscale image, the pixel values have to be set to the averages of the RGB values in principle.i should use a weighting factor for each of the RGB values.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
import numpy as np

myImage = matplotlib.pyplot.imread('flower.png')

height=myImage.shape[0]
width=myImage.shape[1]


for x in range(0, height-1):
  for y in range(0,width-1):
          #insert code

imgplot = matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(myImage)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop.

```
mono = (myImage.mean(2) >= 128) * 255
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative which is more efficient to use: **PIL**

you can install it using

```
pip install pillow \\ pip3 install pillow
```

and import it using `import PIL`

this package has a lot of different ways of converting an image into black and white but I would suggest the easiest method:

```
from PIL import Image

file = "~/Pictures/Test.jpg"
img = Image.open(file)

img = img.convert("L")
img.save("~/Pictures/Test-baw.jpg")
```

if you are interested in other methods, you can also check [this](https://holypython.com/python-pil-tutorial/how-to-convert-an-image-to-black-white-in-python-pil/) out ;)